# Is there a letter? Return wrong value

Tags: java

```
public boolean isThereLetter(String name) {
        char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

        for (char c : chars) {
            if(!Character.isLetter(c)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I called this function like this;

```
if(isThereLetter("Wdasdsa<>")){
        Log.d(TAG, "there is a letter");
    }else
        Log.d(TAG,"there isn't any letter");
```

But I noticed that because of "<" this char in ...("Wdasdsa<>") function returns false. How can I fix it?

Comment: The method name doesn't match what it does. Do you want to return true if there is ATLEAST ONE letter?

Comment: Dude - you're stopping dead and returning "false" the FIRST time you get a NON-LETTER.  That's correct if EVERY character needs to be a letter.  If, instead, you mean "true" if ANY letter: then return "true" the first time you get "isLetter()".  Iinstead of returning "false" the first "!isLetter()".

Answer (score 2):

You've got your conditions backwards. Your current implementation returns `true` iff all characters in the string are letters. It sounds like what you *want* is to return `true` if *any* character in the string is a letter.

```
public boolean isThereLetter(String name) {
    char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars) {
        if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank you everybody I understand my problem. I want to return true at least one letter, but I control string if all characters are letter. thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you came across atleast one characher immediately return true saying that charachet found. Change the code as shown

```
public boolean isThereLetter(String name) {
    char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars) {
        if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
            //You came across atleat one character.
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Never reached into the if block. No any character found
    return false;
}
```